# UML activity diagram: How to end activity after Event Signal Action?

Tags: uml, modeling, diagrams, activity

To my knowledge, event signal actions are not allowed to have output control flow, so how can I model the end of an activity after a event signal action? The same issue arises for accept event actions and activity start nodes.